# Is it possible to split by a substring without removing it?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to do the follow:

I have some strings that I need to separate, they have this form:

```
node:info:sequence(id:ASDF,LMD)
node:info:sequence:id:QWES
```

Those are the possible individual string formats...

Now I have to separate them when come concatenated by comma... like this

```
node:info:sequence(id:ASDF,LMD),node:info:sequence:id:QWES
```

So I tried

```
entries.split(",node");
```

Which... kinda works but of course I cut the "node" part from the previous string, is there anyway I can detect that `,` followed by `node` but split it by the comma `,` only?

Comment: Try `.split(",(?=node\\b)")`

Comment: Try using StringBuffer class

Comment: It should work with a lookahead regex.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor! that worked, could you send it as reply then I can mark this question it as answered?

Comment: At this point I would be looking to write a parser (handling per character) over regex, this looks like you could have enough varied input to give yourself quite a few headaches, especially with the parenthesis and commas there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s.split(",(?=node\\b)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nCbuEG/1/)

The positive lookahead `(?=node\b)` will make sure only those commas are matched that are followed with  a whole word `node` (as the `\b` is a word boundary).